# How could i make this function sleep for a certain amount of time?

Tags: actionscript

So here's my problem. I have code set up that calls a function whenever my player is over its last destination in the a* pathfinding array...

```
public function rakeSoil(e:Event):void {

     var:Cell = Grid.getCellAt(player.x/50, player.y/50);

     if (cell.isWalkable == false) {
         return;
     else {

     //here is where i want to do the sleep code so this doesnt happen straight away? If possible.

     target.sprites = [grass];

     } 
 }
```

thanks guys :)

Comment: Why do you want to make it sleep? How long do you need it to sleep?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the "right" way to delay execution of something is to use a [Timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html).
Hacking up some kind of a sleep function could cause problems, since Flash runs in a single thread, so you won't be able to do anything else while your function is running, including refreshing the screen (making your game appear as if it crashed, or at least started lagging).

If you're absolutely, positively sure you want to do this, you could call the [getTimer()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer%28%29) function in a loop to see if a certain amount of miliseconds has passed.